# parsley data-equalto not working

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I'm trying to match up passwords using Parsley.js but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code:

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Password-->
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-eye-close"></i></span>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-minlength="6">
      </div>
        <p class="help-block">Password should be at least 4 characters</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ************ NOT WORKING *************** -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Password -->
      <label class="control-label"  for="password_confirm">Password (Confirm)</label>
      <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-eye-close"></i></span>
        <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" data-equalto="#password" data-trigger="change focusout" data-required="true" >
      </div>
        <p class="help-block">Please confirm password</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This part **data-equalto="#password"** should do the check, but it doesn't seem to work.

I call the parsley validate in the form like so:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="userForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" data-focus="first" data-validate="parsley">
```

Comment: Who were you, Kevin? What did you see?! http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Try 'data-parsley-equalto' instead of 'data-equalto' (check out http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-list).
It worked for me with parsley.js version 2.2

Answer (score 4):

Been struggling with this for a few hours, found the answer courtesy of [JoelCDoyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457231/joelcdoyle). I want to re-iterate it because though the question is dated, the answer provided by Joel works. Thanks! :)

```
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"
          parsley-minlength="8"
          parsley-required="true"
        />
        <input id="pwtwo" type="password" name="pw-verify"
          data-parsley-equalto="#pw"
          parsley-required="true"
        />
```

this is the attribute you need to make the compare function work with parsley.js:
    `data-parsley-equalto="#pw"`

Comment: how can I change the message?

Comment: data-parsley-equalto-message="Not equal message"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you but I have a working solution here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNyjoY

**Basic installation**

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
...
</form>
```

**Javascript installation** (I'm using this)

```
<form id="form">
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#form').parsley();
</script>
```

I have added an event for `#password` to trigger `#cpassword` form validation.

```
$('#password').on('change input keyup', function() {
    if (this.value) {
      $('#cpassword').prop('required', true).parsley().validate();
    } else {
      $('#cpassword').prop('required', false).parsley().validate();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the newest Parsley Version, you don't call the API by "data-" Attributes anymore. Not quite sure, if this is the case on your Version (i know data values worked in the past), but try it with the New API.

Therefore you call the form different with the property "parsley-validate" which is True if Set. And the Constraints are called with "parsley-[constraint]".
As stated on the official Parsley.js Site, its not quite W3C compatible, but for some weird Reason he likes it like that. However he also gives an Solution with defining a Namespace for Parsley to make it W3C compatible.

If you can Deliver the old Parsley version, I could have a look on that too.

**Attention**

This answer (and maybe question) is dated.
The answer may not be valid anymore, keep a look at the Comments on this answer.

Comment: Well, now it's 2015. From Parsley's website: "Parsley uses a specific DOM API which allows you to configure pretty much everything directly from your DOM, without writing a single javascript configuration line or custom function. Parsley's default DOM API is data-parsley-. That means that if in config you see a foo property, it could be set/modified via DOM with data-parsley-foo="value"."

Comment: Well Parsley was relativly young at that answers time. It evolved pretty fast to a more solid solution for validating Forms. 
I will mark my anser with a note, that its dated. I dont consider rewriting it, as the question may also be dated. :)